# Evaluate My Code Design - Simple Snippet

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        loadCountries();
        loadRegions();
        loadCities();
    }
}

private void loadCountries()
{
    Country country = new Country();
    ddlCountry.DataSource = country.GetDataTable();
    ddlCountry.DataTextField = "countryName";
    ddlCountry.DataValueField = "countryID";
    ddlCountry.DataBind();
}

private void loadRegions()
{
    Region region = new Region();
    ddlRegion.DataSource = region.GetRegionID(ddlCountry.SelectedValue);
    ddlRegion.DataTextField = "regionName";
    ddlRegion.DataValueField = "regionID";
    ddlRegion.DataBind();

}

private void loadCities()
{
    City city = new City();
    ddlCity.DataSource = city.GetCityID(ddlRegion.SelectedValue);
    ddlCity.DataTextField = "cityName";
    ddlCity.DataValueField = "cityID";
    ddlCity.DataBind();
}

protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadRegions();
    if (ddlRegion.SelectedItem.Text == "No Province")
    {
        ddlRegion.Enabled = false;
        loadCities();
    }
    else
    {
        ddlRegion.Enabled = true;
        loadCities();
    }
}
```

The code is back-end of Default.aspx (Presentation layer)

Any business logic related to Country is put into Country class, same rules applied to Region and City.

**Is this snippet design OK? In other words, does it meet the presentation layer standard design? How can i improve this snippet design (if possible)?**

I'm new to this, i try to make sure i take it slowly but surely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the naming conventions need some work. Think carefully about the names of your classes and methods.

For example (class name):

You have a class called Country which suggests it represents a country. But, I don't think it does. It looks like it's responsible for creating a datatable of countries.

and another example (method name):

You have a method called Region.GetRegionID(). It looks (but I'm not completely sure) as if this gets a Region based on a RegionId so i'd prefer GetByRegionId. The same critism of the name of the class applies.

Answer (score 3):

```
void loadDropDown(ComboBox cb, Object Source, string textField, string valueField)
{
   cb.DataSource = Source;
   cb.DataTextField = textField;
   cb.DataValueField = valueField;
   cb.DataBind();
}

//loadRegions
loadDropDown(ddlRegion,  new Region().GetRegionID(ddlCountry.SelectedValue), "regionName", "regionID");

//etc for the other dropdown lists
```

But to more fully answer your question, it looks good.  That code is all UI, so that seems reasonable.  My code was just a small way to DRY.

Comment: This may be on a *tangent*; but I really like it as an extension method; for instance, `ddlRegion.LoadData(new Region().GetRegionID...)`

Comment: @Kman - intellicence doesn't show ddlRegion has LoadData. I only see Load.

Comment: @user311509: Thats an [extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) method. Also checkout an [example of adding custom event using extension method](http://izlooite.blogspot.com/2010/11/c-adding-custom-event.html)

Answer (score 1):

How about this one in ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged?

> loadRegions();
>
> ddlRegion.Enabled = (!ddlRegion.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("No Province"));
>
> loadCities();

Comment: ! Awesome ! ... Creative answer

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are directly using the DataTable in the UI. This will cause maintainability problems in the long run.

You are using DataTable so the column name of the database is used directly in the UI.

So your UI code is directly dependent on the DataAccess layer.

I think you should be using the Business Properties instead of the Database column names.

Comment: Actually, GetDataTable that resides in Business Object Class returns this: "return DAL.GetDataTable(SQLCommand);". DAL is singleton. SQLCommand is passed dynamically in someway (using reflection).

Comment: @user311509: The BusinessObject should return ReadOnlyCollection<CustomObject> or List<CustomObject>. i.e After getting the DataTable should be converted to some List<>, and then the list should be used in the UI layer.